# How to add a custom local font in gantry 5 Joomla theme

Tags: joomla-3.x, gantry

I have tried to add a custom local font(tex-gyre-adventor) in gantry 5 font-picker, but I keep getting this error: "A YAML file cannot contain tabs as indentation at line 46 (near "   tex-gyre-adventor:")"

I added this code in theme.yaml:-

```
  fonts:
    roboto:
      400: 'gantry-theme://fonts/roboto_regular_macroman/Roboto-Regular-webfont'
      500: 'gantry-theme://fonts/roboto_medium_macroman/Roboto-Medium-webfont'
      700: 'gantry-theme://fonts/roboto_bold_macroman/Roboto-Bold-webfont'
    tex-gyre-adventor:
    400: 'gantry-theme://fonts/texgyreadventor-regular-webfont'
    400italic: 'gantry-theme://fonts/texgyreadventor-italic-webfont'
    700: 'gantry-theme://fonts/texgyreadventor-bold-webfont'
    700italic: 'gantry-theme://fonts/texgyreadventor-bolditalic-webfont'
```

Kindly help me resolve this, your assistance is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

YAML files use 2 or 4 spaces for indentation but tab indentation is forbidden.

Use search and replace in your editor to replace each tab with a double space and then check your indentation is correct.

Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19976827/1983389

Comment: I have removed the tabs and added 2 spaces as you've suggested, but now i'm getting this error: "A YAML file cannot contain tabs as indentation at line 51 (near " ")"

Comment: Looks like you are on the right track. :)

Comment: When I check line 51, it's a command block, and when I remove the tabs, I get a series of errors that follow the code is as it's executed. When I remove my added code, there are no errors. Do tabs in YAML mean a newline? Kindly assist